# Configure jest with latest version of d3-path

Tags: javascript, jestjs, babel-jest

For some reason, my jest configuration doesn't work with the latest version of `d3-path@3.0.1`. It worked fine with version `2.0.0`. I guess it has something to do with `d3-path` switching to ESM, but I was already using ES6 in my own code, so I don't get why it suddenly doesn't work anymore. I have the following packages installed:

```
"dependencies": {
  "d3-path": "^3.0.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@babel/core": "^7.15.8",
  "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.8",
  "babel-jest": "^27.3.1",
  "jest": "^27.3.1"
}
```

My `babel.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [['@babel/preset-env', {targets: {node: 'current'}}]],
};
```

My `index.js`:

```
import { path } from 'd3-path'

export default () => path()
```

The test file:

```
import fn from '../src/index.js'

describe('test', () => {
  it('works', () => {
    fn()
    expect(2 + 2).toBe(4)
  })
})
```

The error message:

```
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){export {default as path} from "./path.js";
                                                                                      ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

    > 1 | import { path } from 'd3-path'
```

To reproduce:

```
git clone https://github.com/luucvanderzee/jest-problem.git
cd jest-problem
npm i
npm run test
// The test runs without failure- this is because we're currently still using d3-path@2.0.0
npm uninstall d3-path && npm install d3-path // (upgrade to d3-path@3.0.1)
npm run test
// Now the test fails.
```

How should I configure jest and/or babel to solve this issue?

EDIT:

I already tried the following (from [this](https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules) page of the jest docs):

1. Creating a `jest.config.js` file with the following:

```
module.exports = {
  transform: {}
}
```

2. Changing my `"test"` command from `"jest"` to `"node --experimental-vm-modules node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js"`

This gives me another error:

```
    /home/luuc/Projects/javascript/jest-problem/test/test.test.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){import fn from '../src/index.js'
                                                                                      ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

I also don't get what is meant by

```
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
```

Isn't the problem that the module *is not* transformed? Would adding an ignore pattern not just lead to the module *not* getting transformed?

Comment: Hi Luuc, in the output of `npm run test`, jest explains that the content of `node_modules` is not transformed using Babel by default, and gives pointers on how to change this behaviour. Did you try any of the suggestions?

Comment: Hi Mehdi, sorry I did indeed try that but without success- see edit of original comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problem

The error happens because `jest` does not send the content of `node_modules` to be transformed by babel by default.

The following output line of `npm run test` indicates one way to solve the problem:

> ```
>  • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
> ```

### Solution

The configuration of `jest` should be updated in order to instruct it to transform the `ESM` code present in `d3-path` dependency.

To do so, add the following to a `jest.config.js` file in the root directory of the project:

```
module.exports = {
 transformIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules/(?!(d3-path)/)']
}
```

`npm run test` runs fine after that.

The `transformIgnorePatterns` option is [documented here](https://jestjs.io/docs/tutorial-react-native#transformignorepatterns-customization).

#### Edit - including more modules

In order to include all modules starting with `d3`, the following syntax may be used:

```
 transformIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/(?!(d3.*)/)']
```

Comment: How can I transform multiple dependencies? I also need `d3-scale` and `d3-shape`. The documentation says I have to seperate the dependency names with a pipe, but

```
transformIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules/(?!(d3-path|d3-scale|d3-shape)/)']
```

Fails with

```
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
```

This time, however, the bug occurs in `d3-interpolate`, which is not even a direct depedency. Surely there should be an easier way than adding all direct and indirect dependencies to `transformIgnorePatterns`?

Comment: I've just edited the answer to provide a possible solution for this :)

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR;**

```
transformIgnorePatterns: [
  "/node_modules/(?!d3|d3-array|d3-axis|d3-brush|d3-chord|d3-color|d3-contour|d3-delaunay|d3-dispatch|d3-drag|d3-dsv|d3-ease|d3-fetch|d3-force|d3-format|d3-geo|d3-hierarchy|d3-interpolate|d3-path|d3-polygon|d3-quadtree|d3-random|d3-scale|d3-scale-chromatic|d3-selection|d3-shape|d3-time|d3-time-format|d3-timer|d3-transition|d3-zoom}|internmap|d3-delaunay|delaunator|robust-predicates)"
]
```

For the ones reaching this page after updating recharts dependency, here I found the solution, [provided by them](https://github.com/recharts/recharts/commit/e62d0cf8aaecdc135615c40ae6d95288026d97d5).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).